# Dynamically create Mocha Test Suites

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, mocha.js

I am trying to implement an app which takes testing config/cases as input (yaml/json) files and does bunch of assertions.

```
case:
 - operation: fetch_user
  args:
  - name: id
    value: 1
 - checks:
   - attribute: username
     expected_value: user1
   - attribute: email
     expected_value: user1@test.com
```

I want to write generic test blocks (it()) to perform assertion dynamically.

I've tried [Does mocha/supertest create express server for each test suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60664141/does-mocha-supertest-create-express-server-for-each-test-suite)

I am fetching user information in index.js and have assertion in assertion.js file.

**index.js**

```js
//read yaml file

const body = userService.get(userId);

body.then(userResponse => {
    const suite = createTestSuite("Test", checks, userResponse);
    suite.run();
});
```

**assertion.js**

```js
function createTestSuite(name, checks, userResponse) {
    let suite = new Suite("Moch test");
    suite.addTest(new Test("Check Username", () => {
        expect(userResponse.username).to.equal(checks.expected_username);
    }));

    return suite;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--delay` option should help ([docs](https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite)).

Try something like (untested):

```js
// test.js
// run with `mocha --delay test.js`

// getData will return a Promise which fulfills with an array of test data
getData().then(testData => {
  describe('mocha tests', function() {
    testData.forEach(data => {
      it('should do something with data', function() {
        // assertion here
      });
    });
  });

  run(); // this is a global which starts the test run
});
```

The `--delay` option causes the test run to *wait* until you call `run()`, which allows you to perform async operations (e.g., gather some data) *before* defining tests.

Mocha currently doesn't support asynchronous suites, which makes it awkward to dynamically generate tests from async data sources.